# Updating load balancer failed. Server Certificate not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using Ruby on Rails. Ruby 2.3.5. Rails 5.0.1.

I sign in on [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) as an IAM user. There is one Application called "my_application". I have one environment "development" that is running rails and has all it's migrations and has SSL certificates for that https requests.

I am trying to make another environment, I've tried through the [awsebcli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html). I have tried using the AWS console on my web browser. I can get a sample application going, but whenever I use `eb deploy` in the terminal, I get the same error:

```
$ eb deploy
Creating application version archive "app-1acf-180227_181507".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
ERROR: Updating load balancer named: awseb-e-j-AWSEBLoa-1R5J1B4XC8VQC failed Reason: Server Certificate not found for the key: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/YourSSLCertificate
ERROR: Updating security group named: awseb-e-j7rwf8qps3-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-16BNZKUK6CMIJ failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled
ERROR: Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-j7rwf8qps3-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'  Reason: null
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

What does it mean `Server Certificate not found`?

I used to deploy updates to the other environment, then I got an error during a migration and I've been trying to create a new environment ever since.

I don't remember having to do anything about certificates before. Does the environment need a certificate? Does my computer need a certificate?

I'm assuming it has something to do with my computer because the deployment failure happens pretty early on. If it was code-based, I think the error would be later in the deployment process.